# Error using C string and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

Please I need help with this problem, I can't seem to get around it.
I keep getting this error

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[21]’ from type ‘char *’
       WordList[i].word = token;
```

The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct myWord{
    char word[21];
    int Length;
};

int main(){
    struct myWord WordList[20];
    char myString[] = "the cat in the hat jumped over the lazy fox";
    char *token;
    int i;

    while((token = strtok(myString, " ")) != NULL){
        for(i=0; i<20; i++){
            WordList[i].word = token;
            WordList[i].Length = strlen(token);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
        printf("%s\t%d\n", WordList[i].word, WordList[i].Length);

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 'quick help please'

Answer (score 2):

Arrays do not have the copy assignment operator. You have to copy each element of one array into another array yourself. For character arrays you can use standard C function `strcpy` (or for example `strncpy`) declared in header `<string.h>`

For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( WordList[i].word, token );
```

Or

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strncpy( WordList[i].word, token, sizeof( WordList[i].word ) );
WordList[i].word[sizeof( WordList[i].word ) - 1] = '\0';
```

Take into account that this code snippet

```
while((token = strtok(myString, " ")) != NULL){
    for(i=0; i<20; i++){
        WordList[i].word = token;
        WordList[i].Length = strlen(token);
    }
}
```

is wrong. It could be rewritten the following way

```
i = 0;
if ( (token = strtok(myString, " ") ) != NULL )
{
    do
    {
        strncpy( WordList[i].word, token, sizeof( WordList[i].word ) );
        WordList[i].word[sizeof( WordList[i].word ) - 1] = '\0';
        WordList[i].Length = strlen(token);
        ++i;
    } while ( (token = strtok( NULL , " ") ) != NULL );
}
```

Comment: `strcpy` is not the best advice possible. It's a security vulnerability. +0 for being correct and helpful

Comment: `strncpy` and/or check the string length.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Vlad, you can't copy to an array in this way, another problem is that you are not using `strtok` properly:

> The strtok() function breaks a string into a sequence of zero or
>   more    nonempty tokens.  On the first call to strtok() the string to
>   be    parsed should be specified in str.  **In each subsequent call that
>   should parse the same string, str must be NULL**.

```
token = strtok(myString, " ")
while (token != NULL) {
    /* ... */
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```